# Filter list for dictionaries for key based on a particular value

Tags: python

I have a list of dictionaries:

```
lst = [
    {
        'meter_design': {'S': 'digital'},
        'meter_calibration_period': {'S': '2022'},
        'meter_counting_type': {'S': 'Quantity meter'},
        'meter_kind': {'S': 'Gas'},
        'meter_serial_number': {'S': '10030507'}

    },
    {
       'meter_design': {'S': 'digital'},
       'meter_calibration_period': {'S': '2026'},
       'meter_counting_type': {'S': 'Quantity meter'},
       'meter_kind': {'S': 'Heat'},
       'meter_serial_number': {'S': '7GMT0008942175'}
    }
]
```

that I want to filter to show only the dictionaries, which contain a certain key-value pair like "meter_calibration_period" == '2026'. So far Ive tried this:

```
res = [
       {
        "Calibration" : item["meter_calibration_period"]["S"],
        "serial number" : item["meter_serial_number"]["S"],
       }
          for item in lst if "meter_calibration_period" == '2026'
      ]
```

But I only get back an empty list.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: there's no `meter_serial_number` key in your dicts

Comment: Your condition is creating a list if the string `"meter_calibration_period"` equals the string `'2026'` which never happens (they're pretty different strings ). At no point in the comparison you access the `item` dict. Did you want something like `if item["meter_calibration_period"] == '2026'` or maybe `if item["meter_calibration_period"]["S"] == '2026'` ?

Comment: @BorrajaX  yes, you are right; it must be  `if item["meter_calibration_period"]["S"] == '2026'` - that solves the issue. Tkx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not iterating it properly,

try this:

```py
lst = [
    {
        'meter_design': {'S': 'digital'},
        'meter_calibration_period': {'S': '2022'},
        'meter_counting_type': {'S': 'Quantity meter'},
        'meter_kind': {'S': 'Gas'},
        'meter_serial_number': {'S': '10030507'}

    },
    {
        'meter_design': {'S': 'digital'},
        'meter_calibration_period': {'S': '2022'},
        'meter_counting_type': {'S': 'Quantity meter'},
        'meter_kind': {'S': 'Heat'},
        'meter_serial_number': {'S': '7GMT0008942175'}
    }
]
res = []
for i in lst:
    if i['meter_calibration_period']['S'] == '2022':
        res.append(i)

for i in res:
    print(i)
```